# regular expression for date and time validation format

Tags: validation, date, datetime

I found a regular expression to validate this date format: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM

^(?=\d)(?:(?!(?:1582(?:.|-|/)10(?:.|-|/)(?:0?[5-9]|1[0-4]))|(?:1752(?:.|-|/)0?9(?:.|-|/)(?:0?[3-9]|1[0-3])))(?=(?:(?!000[04]|(?:(?:1[^0-6]|[2468][^048]|[3579][^26])00))(?:(?:\d\d)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))\D0?2\D29)|(?:\d{4}\D(?!(?:0?[2469]|11)\D31)(?!0?2(?:.|-|/)(?:29|30))))(\d{4})([-/.])(0?\d|1[012])\2((?!00)[012]?\d|3[01])(?:$|(?=\x20\d)\x20))?((?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?::[0-5]\d){0,2}(?:\x20[aApP][mM]))|(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::[0-5]\d){1,2})?$

How do I change the expression above to validate this format: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (i have created my own.. as the example you gave doesnt seem to work):

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d\s{1}(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)\s{1}([aApP][mM]){1}$
```